# Нужно переменную score вывести за пределами функции draw так чтоб счетчик работал

Tags: javascript

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Flappy Bird!</title>
</head>
<body>

 <canvas id="canvas" width="288" height="512"></canvas><br>
 <canvas id="canvas2" width="250" height="50"></canvas>
 <script src="js/game.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
       //задаются параметры htm canvas
        var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
         var cvs2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
        var ctx2 = cvs2.getContext("2d");
        var gap = 95;

        //bird позиция
        var x = 10;
        var y = 150;
        var grav = 1.5;


        //create blocks
        var pipe=[];
        pipe[0]={
            x: cvs.width,
            y: 0
        }

        //задаются картинки
        var bird = new Image();
        var backg = new Image();
        var frontg = new Image();
        var pipeUp = new Image();
        var pipeBottom = new Image();

        bird.src = "img/bird.png";
        backg.src = "img/bg.png";
        frontg.src = "img/fg.png";
        pipeUp.src = "img/pipeUp.png";
        pipeBottom.src = "img/pipeBottom.png";


        //audio files
        var flyA = new Audio();
        var scoreA = new Audio();

        flyA.src = "audio/fly.mp3";
        scoreA.src = "audio/score.mp3";

        //нажать кнопку
        document.addEventListener("keydown",moveUp);

        function moveUp(){
            y -= 25;
            flyA.play();
        }
        var score = 0;
        //get images
        function draw(){


            ctx.drawImage(backg,0,0);
            for(var i=0; i<pipe.length; i++){
            ctx.drawImage(pipeUp,pipe[i].x,pipe[i].y);
            ctx.drawImage(pipeBottom,pipe[i].x,pipe[i].y
                +pipeUp.height + gap);

            pipe[i].x--;

            if(pipe[i].x == 125){
                pipe.push({
                    x:cvs.width,
                    y:Math.floor(Math.random()*
                        pipeUp.height) -
                     pipeUp.height
                    });
                   }
        if(x+bird.width >= pipe[i].x 
            && x<=pipe[i].x+pipeUp.width
            &&(y<=pipe[i].y + pipeUp.height 
            || y + bird.height >= pipe[i].y +pipeUp.height +gap)|| y + bird.height >= cvs.height - frontg.height){
            location.reload();
        }
        if (pipe[i].x == 5) {

            score++;
            scoreA.play();
        }
            }

            ctx.drawImage(frontg,0,cvs.height - frontg.height);

            ctx.drawImage(bird,x,y);

            y += grav;
            requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        }
        pipeBottom.onload = draw;

    //вывести тут
                  ctx2.fillStyle= "black";
            ctx2.font = "24px Verdana";
            ctx2.fillText("Score: "+score,25,20);
```

Comment: Ну и в чём проблема?

Comment: Выводит только значение 0, которое присвоено в начале, но а мне надо score, кторый уже изменен в этой функции в цикле for    if (pipe[i].x == 5) {

            score++;
            scoreA.play();
        }

Comment: как его вытащить из функции?

Comment: Значит условие `pipe[i].x == 5` не выполняется

Comment: оно выполняется , но внутри функции,

Comment: как мне из этой функции выразить переменную score?

Comment: гляньте пожалуйста - https://github.com/ilyag26/flappyBird

Comment: блин, задача-то какая? не могу понять. вы **не** хотите, что бы код `ctx2.fillText...` выполнялся в функции `draw`?